# Window titlebar scaling problem with Marco

Tags: mate, metacity, hdpi

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 beta2, and Marco as my window manager. The following two screenshots illustrate the problem: with HiDPI turned off, the window title bar looks as described by the theme file:

[image: LoDPI]

But with HiDPI turned on, these bars appear in the title bar and around the window action buttons:

[image: HiDPI]

How do I avoid this?

For reference, here is the full `metacity-theme-1.xml` file for the theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metacity_theme>
<info>
  <name>HeliX-Sweetpill Crowberry</name>
  <author>Andrew Bradford &lt;ajbradford@comcast.net&gt;</author>
  <copyright>&#194; Andrew Bradford, 2002 Licensed under GPL</copyright>
  <date>November 5, 2002</date>
  <description>Port of HeliX-Sweetpill Crowberry to Metacity</description>
</info>

<frame_geometry name="normal">
  <distance name="left_width" value="6"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="6"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="6"/>
  <distance name="left_titlebar_edge" value="4"/>
  <distance name="right_titlebar_edge" value="4"/>
  <distance name="button_width" value="17"/>
  <distance name="button_height" value="17"/>
  <distance name="title_vertical_pad" value="0"/>
  <border name="title_border" left="0" right="0" top="5" bottom="5"/>
  <border name="button_border" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1"/>
</frame_geometry>

<frame_geometry name="border" parent="normal" has_title="false">
  <distance name="button_width" value="0"/>
  <distance name="button_height" value="6"/>
  <border name="title_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
  <border name="button_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
</frame_geometry>

<draw_ops name="title_text">
  <clip x="17" y="0" width="width - 32" height="height"/>
  <title color="white" x="(width - title_width) / 2" y="(height - title_height) / 2"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="title_text_off">
  <clip x="17" y="0" width="width - 32" height="height"/>
  <title color="blend/white/black/0.2" x="(width - title_width) / 2" y="(height - title_height) / 2"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="blank">
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="title">
  <image filename="title_left.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_mid.png" x="43" y="0" width="width - 128" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_right.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="title_off">
  <image filename="title_left_off.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_mid_off.png" x="43" y="0" width="width - 128" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_right_off.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="title_shade">
  <image filename="title_left_shade.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_mid.png" x="43" y="0" width="width - 128" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_right_shade.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="title_shade_off">
  <image filename="title_left_shade_off.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_mid_off.png" x="43" y="0" width="width - 128" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_right_shade_off.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="utility_title">
  <image filename="title_left.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_mid.png" x="43" y="0" width="width - 90" height="height"/>
  <image filename="utility_title_right.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="utility_title_off">
  <image filename="title_left_off.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_mid_off.png" x="43" y="0" width="width - 90" height="height"/>
  <image filename="utility_title_right_off.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="utility_title_shade">
  <image filename="title_left_shade.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_mid.png" x="43" y="0" width="width - 90" height="height"/>
  <image filename="utility_title_right_shade.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="utility_title_shade_off">
  <image filename="title_left_shade_off.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="title_mid_off.png" x="43" y="0" width="width - 90" height="height"/>
  <image filename="utility_title_right_shade_off.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="border_top">
  <image filename="border_topleft.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="border_top.png" x="6" y="0" width="width-12" height="height"/>
  <image filename="border_topright.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="border_shade">
  <image filename="border_topleft_shade.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
  <image filename="border_top_shade.png" x="6" y="0" width="width - 12" height="height"/>
  <image filename="border_topright_shade.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="border_left">
  <image filename="border_left.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="border_right">
  <image filename="border_right.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="border_bottom">
  <image filename="border_bottomleft.png" x="0" y="0" width="object_width" height="object_height"/>
  <image filename="border_bottom.png" x="6" y="0" width="width - 12" height="object_height"/>
  <image filename="border_bottomright.png" x="width - object_width" y="0" width="object_width" height="object_height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_close">
  <image filename="button_close.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_close_off">
  <image filename="button_close_off.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_close_in">
  <image filename="button_close_in.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_min">
  <image filename="button_min.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_min_off">
  <image filename="button_min_off.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_min_in">
  <image filename="button_min_in.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_max">
  <image filename="button_max.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_max_off">
  <image filename="button_max_off.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_max_in">
  <image filename="button_max_in.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_menu">
  <image filename="button_menu.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_menu_off">
  <image filename="button_menu_off.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="button_menu_in">
  <image filename="button_menu_in.png" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
</draw_ops>

<frame_style name="normal_focused" geometry="normal">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="title"/>
  <piece position="left_edge" draw_ops="border_left"/>
  <piece position="right_edge" draw_ops="border_right"/>
  <piece position="bottom_edge" draw_ops="border_bottom"/>
  <piece position="title" draw_ops="title_text"/>
  <button function="close" state="normal" draw_ops="button_close"/>
  <button function="close" state="pressed" draw_ops="button_close_in"/>
  <button function="minimize" state="normal" draw_ops="button_min"/>
  <button function="minimize" state="pressed" draw_ops="button_min_in"/>
  <button function="maximize" state="normal" draw_ops="button_max"/>
  <button function="maximize" state="pressed" draw_ops="button_max_in"/>
  <button function="menu" state="normal" draw_ops="button_menu"/>
  <button function="menu" state="pressed" draw_ops="button_menu_in"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="normal_unfocused" geometry="normal">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="title_off"/>
  <piece position="left_edge" draw_ops="border_left"/>
  <piece position="right_edge" draw_ops="border_right"/>
  <piece position="bottom_edge" draw_ops="border_bottom"/>
  <piece position="title" draw_ops="title_text_off"/>
  <button function="close" state="normal" draw_ops="button_close"/>
  <button function="close" state="pressed" draw_ops="button_close_in"/>
  <button function="minimize" state="normal" draw_ops="button_min"/>
  <button function="minimize" state="pressed" draw_ops="button_min_in"/>
  <button function="maximize" state="normal" draw_ops="button_max"/>
  <button function="maximize" state="pressed" draw_ops="button_max_in"/>
  <button function="menu" state="normal" draw_ops="button_menu"/>
  <button function="menu" state="pressed" draw_ops="button_menu_in"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="normal_shade_focused" geometry="normal" parent="normal_focused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="title_shade"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="normal_shade_unfocused" geometry="normal" parent="normal_unfocused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="title_shade_off"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="utility_focused" geometry="normal" parent="normal_focused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="utility_title"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="utility_unfocused" geometry="normal" parent="normal_unfocused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="utility_title_off"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="utility_shade_focused" geometry="normal" parent="utility_focused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="utility_title_shade"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="utility_shade_unfocused" geometry="normal" parent="utility_unfocused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="utility_title_shade_off"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="border_focused" geometry="border" parent="normal_focused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="border_top"/>
  <piece position="title" draw_ops="blank"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="border_unfocused" geometry="border" parent="normal_unfocused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="border_top"/>
  <piece position="title" draw_ops="blank"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="border_shade_focused" geometry="border" parent="border_focused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="border_shade"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style name="border_shade_unfocused" geometry="border" parent="border_unfocused">
  <piece position="titlebar" draw_ops="border_shade"/>
</frame_style>

<frame_style_set name="normal">
  <frame focus="yes" state="normal" resize="both" style="normal_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="normal" resize="both" style="normal_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="maximized" style="normal_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="maximized" style="normal_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="shaded" style="normal_shade_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="shaded" style="normal_shade_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="maximized_and_shaded" style="normal_shade_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="maximized_and_shaded" style="normal_shade_unfocused"/>
</frame_style_set>

<frame_style_set name="utility">
  <frame focus="yes" state="normal" resize="both" style="utility_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="normal" resize="both" style="utility_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="maximized" style="utility_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="maximized" style="utility_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="shaded" style="utility_shade_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="shaded" style="utility_shade_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="maximized_and_shaded" style="utility_shade_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="maximized_and_shaded" style="utility_shade_unfocused"/>
</frame_style_set>

<frame_style_set name="border">
  <frame focus="yes" state="normal" resize="both" style="border_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="normal" resize="both" style="border_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="maximized" style="border_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="maximized" style="border_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="shaded" style="border_shade_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="shaded" style="border_shade_unfocused"/>
  <frame focus="yes" state="maximized_and_shaded" style="border_shade_focused"/>
  <frame focus="no" state="maximized_and_shaded" style="border_shade_unfocused"/>
</frame_style_set>

<window type="normal" style_set="normal"/>
<window type="dialog" style_set="utility"/>
<window type="modal_dialog" style_set="utility"/>
<window type="menu" style_set="utility"/>
<window type="utility" style_set="utility"/>
<window type="border" style_set="border"/>

<menu_icon function="close" state="normal" draw_ops="button_close"/>
<menu_icon function="maximize" state="normal" draw_ops="button_max"/>
<menu_icon function="unmaximize" state="normal" draw_ops="button_max"/>
<menu_icon function="minimize" state="normal" draw_ops="button_min"/>
</metacity_theme>
```

Comment: It would be better if you inform http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .